# My Webview Reloads When I Change From Portrait To Landscape

Tags: webview

I have a simple `WebView` that runs a web application on an Android. The problem is when I rotate the phone to change it to landscape the `webview` reloads and goes back to the beginning.

How can I prevent this action?

Ron

Answer (score 52):

> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also
> changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
>
> ```
> <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
> ```

Excerpt from [Handle configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) ([webarchive to original page](http://web.archive.org/web/20120130201824/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html))

Answer (score 7):

This can be resolved by overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` in your activity and calling `saveState` from the Webview:

This [blog post](http://roman-dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-webview-orientation-changes.html) may be of help to you.

Comment: This appears to be the bestest answer. You should add all the code snippets, though. :-)

Comment: I am working on my first app. the same problem happening if i am minimizing the app. how it can be prevented

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to your AndroidManifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

So it should look something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
```

Obviously, if your WebView needs keyboard support then don't include the keyboard options.

Comment: That doesn't fix the reloading problem.

Answer (score 3):

Add this before the oncreate

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
webview.saveState(outState);
}
```

Write the oncreate this way. put final

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);
if (savedInstanceState != null)
{
((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
else
{
webview.loadUrl("http://www.playbuzz.org/");
}

}
```

In Androidmanifest insert under the activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: can i use webview as an android app by making mobile or tab compatible website & putting entire website on webview?

Comment: screenSize is needed too, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11903662/5189680

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Add above method in your activity.. and

android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"

in your manifest file

Comment: The question wasn't how to enable orientation change, but how to prevent reload on orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above solution is that it renders the screen white for some time before the webview redraws the contents.

Try using 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" inside your AndroidManifest.xml file for the activity that displays the webview. That should help.

Comment: That doesn't fix the reloading problem either

Answer (score 1):

Add in Activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: screenSize is needed too, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11903662/5189680